# java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString() length

Tags: java, string, random, uuid, string-length

Does java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString() length always equal to 36?

I was not able to find info on that. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) it is said only the following:

> public static UUID randomUUID()
>   Static factory to retrieve a type 4 (pseudo randomly generated) UUID. The UUID is generated using a cryptographically strong pseudo random number generator.
>   Returns:
>   A randomly generated UUID

And that `type 4` tells me nothing. I do not know what type 4 means in the case.

Comment: Since UUIDs have a defined length, yes.

Comment: What part of ['a UUID represents a 128-bit value'](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) did you fail to understand?

Comment: Here is what the Javadoc says about types: The version field holds a value that describes the type of this UUID. There are four different basic types of UUIDs: time-based, DCE security, name-based, and randomly generated UUIDs. These types have a version value of 1, 2, 3 and 4, respectively.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

> Does java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString() length always equal to 36?

## **Yes!!** it is.

A `UUID` actually a 128 bit value (2 long). To represent 128 bit into hex string there will be `128/4=32` char (each char is 4bit long). In string format it also contains 4 (`-`) that's why the length is 36.

### Example: `54947df8-0e9e-4471-a2f9-9af509fb5889`

32 hex char + 4 hyphen char = 36 char. So the length will be always same.

---

#Update:

> I do not know what type 4 means in the case.?

FYI: There are several ways to generate UUID. Here **type-4** means this uuid is generated using a **random** or **pseudo-random number**. From wiki - [Universally_unique_identifier#Versions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Versions):

## [UUID Versions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Versions)

For both variants 1 and 2, five "versions" are defined in the standards, and each version may be more appropriate than the others in specific use cases. Version is indicated by the M in the string representation.

> **Version 1** UUIDs are generated from a time and a node id (usually the MAC address);

> **version 2** UUIDs are generated from an identifier (usually a group or user id), time, and a node id;

> **versions 3 and 5** produce deterministic UUIDs generated by hashing a namespace identifier and name;

> and **version 4** UUIDs are generated using a random or pseudo-random number.

Comment: So, it's always 32 alphanumeric characters plus 4 hyphens?

Comment: Yes it is. 36 char long string.

Comment: "32 alphanumeric characters" is not actually correct. It should be `32 hexOctet and `hexOctet = <hexDigit><hexDigit>` 

`hexDigit               =
       "0" | "1" | "2" | "3" | "4" | "5" | "6" | "7" | "8" | "9"
       | "a" | "b" | "c" | "d" | "e" | "f"
       | "A" | "B" | "C" | "D" | "E" | "F"`.

Answer (score 5):

You may convert UUIDv4 16 bytes binary to 24 bytes ascii using base64, instead encode to ascii-hex (32 bytes)

Comment: try to highlight the keywords and be clear with the format it will help to reach out your answer for others

Comment: That's a nice idea, for instance I have to integrate a UUID-v4-based identifiers system with another system which limits IDs to 30 charactes max length.

Answer (score 4):

For those like me that start googling before reading the javadoc, here the javadoc ;)

[UUID.toString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#toString--)

For those that Don't know how to read a grammar tree read from Bottom to Top.
an **hexDigit** is one char
an **hexOctet** is 2 hexDigits = 2chars
a **node** is 6 * hexOctet = 6 * 2hexdigit = 6*2 chars = 12chars
a **variant**_and_sequence is 2 * hexOctet = 2 * 2hexdigit = 2*2 chars = 4chars
a **time_high_and_version** is 2 * hexOctet = 2 * 2hexdigit = 2*2 chars = 4chars
a **time_mid** is 2 * hexOctet = 2 * 2hexdigit = 2*2 chars = 4chars
a **time_low** is 4 * hexOctet = 4* 2hexdigit = 4*2 chars = 8chars
and finaly, a **UUID** is < time_low > "-" < time_mid > "-" < time_high_and_version > "-" < variant_and_sequence > "-"< node >

= 8 chars + 1 char + 4 chars + 1 char + 4 chars + 1 char + 4 chars + 1 char + 12 chars

= 36 chars ! 128 bit of data + 4 hyphen as stated previously

```
The UUID string representation is as described by this BNF: 

 UUID                   = <time_low> "-" <time_mid> "-"
                          <time_high_and_version> "-"
                          <variant_and_sequence> "-"
                          <node>
 time_low               = 4*<hexOctet>
 time_mid               = 2*<hexOctet>
 time_high_and_version  = 2*<hexOctet>
 variant_and_sequence   = 2*<hexOctet>
 node                   = 6*<hexOctet>
 hexOctet               = <hexDigit><hexDigit>
 hexDigit               =
       "0" | "1" | "2" | "3" | "4" | "5" | "6" | "7" | "8" | "9"
       | "a" | "b" | "c" | "d" | "e" | "f"
       | "A" | "B" | "C" | "D" | "E" | "F"
```