# Asserting UUID in junit

Tags: java, junit, uuid

I have a method which builds an object and returns it.

The object as UUID as one of its fields. While building the object, random UUID is generated. Here is the code:

```
public MetaData getMetaData(String id) {
  return MetaData.newBuilder().setId(id)
    .setCorrelationId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
    .setCreatedAt(now(UTC).format(ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME))
    .build();
}
```

Here is my test:

```
@Test
public void shouldVerifyIfTheMetaDataIsBuild() {

  MetaData metaData = handler.getMetaData("1234");

  assertThat(metaData.getId(), is("1234"));
  assertThat(metaData.getCorrelationId(), isNotNull());
}
```

I'm just verifying if the `correlationId` is not null or not. Is there a better way to verify the `UUID`?

Comment: Seems like you don't want to do static mocking. In that case it can be enough to check that it is not blank, or maybe that it has the length of a UUID string, etc.

Comment: Yeah. I dont want to do static mocking

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only way to verify the current production code is to, yes, check that CorrelationId is not null. You could also check that the layout of the expected string matches a valid UUID string.

Of course, when you want to a bit of better checking, then you simply have to replace `UUID.randomUUID().toString()` with something that you can **control**.

For example you could create a `UUIDGenerator` interface, with a default method that creates a *random* UUID, as shown in your code. But in your test setup, you instead provide an implementation of that interface that returns a *specific* UUID.

Then your test code could *know* which UUID should be used, and `assertThat(actualUuid, is(expectedUuid))`.

Answer (score 7):

I would change this line:

```
assertThat(metaData.getCorrelationId().toString(), isNotNull());
```

to the following:

```
assertThat(metaData.getCorrelationId(), isNotNull());
```

otherwise you would get a `NullPointerException` if `metaData.getCorrelationId()` returns `null` instead of an assertion failure.

Additionally, you could test if `metaData.getCorrelationId()` returns a string that represents a valid UUID, by trying to parse it:

```
try {
    UUID.fromString(metaData.getCorrelationID());
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    fail("Correlation ID is not a valid UUID: " + metaData.getCorrelationId());
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! my bad, I have updated the question. Removed toString()

Comment: @GhostCat `metaData.getCorrelationID()` is apparently a `String` looking at OP's code.

Comment: Uups. Too many confusing `toString()` calls in that original question ... you are right!

Answer (score 4):

When using a UUID, I check the String pattern using a regex.

```
assertTrue(id.matches(Pattern("([a-f0-9]{8}(-[a-f0-9]{4}){4}[a-f0-9]{8})")))
```

This way I check if it is present and if the String is indeed a UUID as I had it happen that an unintended change put a space there which would pass in the `assertNotNull` solutions.

Comment: More apt way to match the Pattern in java is `Pattern.matches("([a-f0-9]{8}(-[a-f0-9]{4}){4}[a-f0-9]{8})", metaData.getCorrelationID());`

Answer (score 1):

One more thing you can validate about UUID is it's length (as it is always 36 [java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString() length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45388021/java-util-uuid-randomuuid-tostring-length)).

There will be a chance for detecting changes in implementation in future.

Answer (score 1):

I added a UUID validator to Apache Commons Validator. It's not yet been merged, but you can vote for it here: https://github.com/apache/commons-validator/pull/68

Answer (score 0):

As rightly said by @GhostCat, since we don't have control over `UUID.randomUUID()`, the only way would be to check if the UUID generated is not null. For that, you may use the code below:

```
assertNotNull(metaData.getCorrelationId());
```