# Generate long fixed size random String

Tags: java, uuid

I want to generate unique 25 characters and numbers long string using the following code,

```
public static String generateString() {
   String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
   return uuid;
}
```

How I can set the size of the generated String and remove the `-` symbols?

Comment: UUID cannot come with a fixed size

Answer (score 5):

UUID is of fixed size, if you just want to get rid of `-` use `replace` as mentioned above or else you have to substring to get the desired length. Also, keep in mind UUID has defined length of 16-byte.

Reference: [java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString() length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45388021/java-util-uuid-randomuuid-tostring-length)

Answer (score 3):

Use `replace()`

```
uuid = uuid.replace("-", "");
```

Comment: Thanks, but how I can set the fixed size?

Comment: what do you mean by the fixed size?

Comment: For example I want always to generate 25 characters long string.

Comment: Strings are Immutable

Comment: @JBNizet No, it will compile fine but strings are immutable

Comment: @BasilBattikhi now it will. At the time I commented, when the code was different, it wouldn't.

Comment: @JBNizet yeah. that was my mistake. Apologies...

Comment: @JBNizet He did nothing else reassigning uuid the code is stil as it was

Comment: @BasilBattikhi actually I did `char -> String`.

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala yes i just saw the edit history, You cant have empty single qout

Comment: @PeterPenzov the size is fixed. You'll always get 32 characters long String value after replacing `-`.